# MathJax on questions display page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mathjax

The MathJax only renders correctly for some of my questions on my profile page, but when I click through to the question, it will render correctly.

[image]

Comment: It works fine for me. Does this issue persist for you over multiple refreshes?

Comment: Oh wow, it seems to have gone away now.  I guess this can be called "status-norepro" or something like that.

Comment: MathJax sometimes has this glitch where it stops rendering partway through the page. Refreshing invariably fixes it. Also, if this is no longer a problem, you can always just delete the question.

Comment: what web browser and OS please? I agree it's probably just a MathJax quirk, but I would still like to know.

Comment: Chrome / on the good ol' 7.  Yes I stopped using XP =).